# Is the power regression/overheating bug fixed in Kernel 3.2?

Tags: kernel

Has this issue been dealt with in the latest Kernel 3.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am guessing you are talking about laptops, video cards and specially Intel ones. There is an improvement mentioned in sites like Phoronix and OMGUbuntu but for what I have tested, is not yet activated. It should be by the end of 12.04 since the patches and changes are going to be applied to the 3.2 kernel anyway, which is the default for 12.04 now.

Why I suggest is to wait for the final release since this is an Alpha and an Alpha 1 for that matter and since our problem is very bad (power sucked out quickly and temperatures really bad) it is better to test it with something stable than something not quite finished yet.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. You guessed right the bug affects almost all Intel powered laptops. I pray the final release (12.04) solves this problem once and for all. I can't boot into 11.10 as it is just too HOT to handle

Comment: Correct. It gets really hot really fast. Does not matter if you are in the artic with it. But with the several fixes made in 3.2 mos power regressions, heat problems and even video and sandy bridge problems should be gone.

Comment: Really hope so as these past few months without Ubuntu has been awful

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't/won't be fixed in 3.2. See http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTAyMjk

Comment: Canonical will likely end up patching it for their "Precise
Pangolin" kernel. From the article it seems Canonical will in it's own way patch the mainstream Kernel with a fix

Comment: UPDATE: A fix has now been included in the Ubuntu Precise kernel and is pending release.